# Stored procedure and VB.net code not working : Too many arguments

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures

I have the following stored procedure:

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE p_InsertNewBatch
(
@customer_id VARCHAR(50),
@batch_number INT,
@batch_reference VARCHAR(50),
@output_location VARCHAR(150),
@create_date VARCHAR(50),
@batchid INT OUTPUT
)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
declare @date datetime
set @create_date= convert(VARCHAR, @create_date, 1) -- as dd/mm/yyyy

INSERT INTO tbl_batches
(
[customer_id],
[batch_number],
[batch_reference],
[batch_output_location],
[create_date]
)
VALUES
(
@customer_id,
@batch_number,
@batch_reference,
@output_location,
@create_date
)
SELECT @batchid = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
END
```

And I run this stored procedure form a form OnCLick event:

```vb
Dim con As New SqlConnection
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
Dim intRowsAffected As Integer

'Try
Dim returnbatch As Integer = 0
Dim customerID As String
Dim batchref As String
Dim todaysdate As String = String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", DateTime.Now)
Dim batchid As Integer
Dim myClientFolder As String
Dim myBatchFolder As String

con.ConnectionString = My.Settings.TestValue()
con.Open()
cmd.Connection = con
cmd.CommandText = "p_GetNextBatchNumber"
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
cmd.Parameters.Add("@CustomerID", SqlDbType.Char)
cmd.Parameters("@CustomerID").Value = txtCustomerNumber.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add("@NextBatch", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
con.Close()

returnbatch = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters("@NextBatch").Value)
batchref = txtCustomerNumber.Text & "-" & returnbatch
txtBatchNumber.Text = returnbatch
txtBatchReference.Text = batchref
txtCreateDate.Text = todaysdate
customerID = txtCustomerNumber.Text

myClientFolder = "c:\Scanned Batches1\" & txtCustomerNumber.Text
myBatchFolder = "c:\Scanned Batches1\" & txtCustomerNumber.Text & "\" & txtBatchReference.Text

If Directory.Exists(myClientFolder) Then
Else
    MsgBox("A new folder for this client will be created")
    Directory.CreateDirectory(myClientFolder)
End If
' Now check that the Batch ID folder exists
If Directory.Exists(myBatchFolder) Then
    MsgBox("A batch folder already exists with this name.  Are you sure you want to continue", vbInformation)
Else
    MsgBox("A new folder for this batch will be created", vbInformation)
    Directory.CreateDirectory(myBatchFolder)
End If

txtOutputLoc.Text = "c:\Scanned Batches1\" & txtCustomerNumber.Text & "\" & txtBatchReference.Text
txtOutputLoc.Enabled = False


'INSERT into tbl_Batches the Batch Details 

' @customer_id VARCHAR(50),
' @batch_number INT,
' @batch_reference VARCHAR(50),
' @output_location VARCHAR(150),
' @create_date datetime 


con.Open()
cmd.CommandText = "p_InsertNewBatch"
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

cmd.Parameters.Add("@customer_id", SqlDbType.Char).Value = customerID
cmd.Parameters.Add("@batch_number", SqlDbType.Int).Value = returnbatch
cmd.Parameters.Add("@batch_reference", SqlDbType.Char).Value = batchref
cmd.Parameters.Add("@output_location", SqlDbType.Char).Value = txtOutputLoc.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add("@create_date", SqlDbType.Char).Value = todaysdate
cmd.Parameters.Add("@batchid", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
intRowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()


con.Close()
batchid = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters("@batchid").Value)
txtID.Text = batchid

'Catch ex As Exception
'MessageBox.Show("Error while trying to add new batch..." & ex.Message, "Create Batch")
' Finally
con.Close()
'End Try

End Sub
```

However I keep getting an error :

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException was unhandled
>   Procedure or function p_InsertNewBatch has too many arguments specified.

What's going on here?  I've been looking over the code for ages and can't seem to see whats causing it.

Thanks

Comment: Check the value of your parameters.

Comment: Side note: Why on earth would you convert today's date into a *string* to pass it across to the database and thus *introduce* formatting issues - since you're using parameters, you can keep it as a `DateTime` variable in your VB and a `datetime` in the database and rely on ADO.NET to safely translate between the two.

Answer (score 2):

You're using a single command object to execute multiple SQL statements but you don't clear the parameters from the first one before adding new parameters for the second one.  I would tend to create a new command object for each SQL statement but, if you're going to use the same one and change the `CommandText` then make sure that you clear the parameters too.

Comment: How many things in your code have a `CommandText` property and parameters?  How many things in your code have "command" in the name?  Only one, so that's obviously the command object.  I mean instead of creating one of those objects and using it multiple times, create a new one for each use.